# is it necessary to install VS 2010 on server while migrating from .net 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have project in .net 2.0 with visual studio 2008.

I want to migrate to .net 4.0.

So is it necessary to install VS 2010.

Or with VS 2008 i can use .net 4.0 ???

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2008 support .NET framework 3.5 max.. 
You will have to use VS2010 to work on .NET framework 4.0

Comment: You have ShartDevelop - http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/ if you dont mind open source IDE

Comment: But if you are really sticking to VS, then no you do not have other alternative apart from purchasing VS2010 to work on .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

4.0 is different from the previous .NET versions, vs2008 does not support 4.0. You have to migrate to VS2010 if you want to upgrade to 4.0.

Comment: You can upgrade to vs2012 or vs2013. Or you can have a look at the express version: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673. Which is free.